# Parsing a PHP Array with Decode

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I am having a challenge correctly parsing an array in PHP. Here is the output of the array:

```
[{"address":"2801 Elliott Ave","category_ids":[347],"category_labels":[["Social","Food and 
Dining","Restaurants"]],"country":"us","email":"kimd@thedussingroup.com","factual_id":"43cfe23
8-ae8e-469a-8592-a1edc8603051","fax":"(206) 448-
9252","latitude":47.615154,"locality":"Seattle","longitude":-122.353724,"name":"The Old 
Spaghetti Factory","neighborhood":["Belltown","Downtown","Downtown 
Seattle"],"postcode":"98121","region":"WA","tel":"(206) 441-
7724","website":"http:\/\/www.osf.com"}]
```

And here is the parsing attempt...

```
$mark = array("[");
$mark2 = array("]");
$replacemark  = array("");
$array = str_replace($mark, $replacemark, $array);
$array = str_replace($mark2, $replacemark, $array);
$array = stripslashes($array);

$obj = json_decode($array);

$address = $obj->{'address'};
$country = $obj->{'country'};
$factual_id = $obj->{'factual_id'};
$latitude = $obj->{'latitude'};
$locality = $obj->{'locality'};
$longitude = $obj->{'longitude'};
$name = $obj->{'name'};
$postcode = $obj->{'postcode'};
$region = $obj->{'region'};
$status = $obj->{'status'};
$tel = $obj->{'tel'};
```

Any ideas why these values are not returning anything? Thanks!

Comment: What is all the replacing atop supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to strip the square brackets. Simply call `json_decode()` on the data and retrieve your information.

**Note:** the data in the form you have it decodes to an array of objects, with just one object, so you need to provide an array subscript:

```
$json = json_decode("My JSON Data...here");
echo $json[0]->address;
```

See [this fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/r4g-552)

**2nd Note:** the data as you have posted it has embedded newlines which caused a problem with `json_decode()`. If you have those in your original data you'll need to strip them before decoding. I edited them out in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the square brackets in the JSON string, and then try accessing your values like `$obj->address`

Edit:

That JSON string returns an array with your object at index 0, tested myself, so to access your values you will need to: `$obj[0]->address` or set your object `$obj = $de_json[0];` and accessing values as I said above

Comment: `json_decode()` is returning `NULL` with and without the brackets

Comment: works fine for me, only problem is that the JSON string when decoded returns an array containing the object at index 0 so the above needs some adjusting